# accepting keys without loop in quickbasic

Tags: dos, quickbasic

I'm working on an program that opens up different programs for each different key inside QuickBasic 4.5 (for a game.) Unfortunately, looping more than one INKEY$ command causes it to not register most of the time.

Is there any library/method to get around this?

Here's what I put in:

```
DO    
IF INKEY$ = "n" GOTO 2000
IF INKEY$ = "y" GOTO 3000
IF INKEY$ = "e" GOTO 4000
LOOP
```

Comment: Save the key to a variable then compare it. Each use of `INKEY$` reads another character.

Comment: How would I do that? (I am a noob at this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. But I suggest you start with learning how to save to variables, and you do not need GOTO in Basic, there are other ways which makes the program easier to change in the future.

```
DIM KeyPressed AS STRING

INPUT "Please Enter A Key (y,n,e): ", KeyPressed

KeyPressed = LCASE$(KeyPressed)

SELECT CASE KeyPressed
  CASE "n"
     GOTO 2000
  CASE "y"
     GOTO 3000
  CASE "e"
     GOTO 4000
END SELECT
```

Comment: Your UCASE$ should be changed to LCASE$

Comment: @eoredson, correct. I've changed it now. Thanks for noticing it.